# If localstorage key exists, append <li>

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I have a small offline app which you can create boxes dynamically and the boxes are stored in localstorage. The boxes are `<li>`'s.

The HTML Looks like this:

```
<ul id="bxs" class="tabs"> 

            <li id="item-1">1</li> 
            <li id="item-2">2</li> 
            <li id="item-3">3</li> 
            <li id="item-4">4</li> 
            // etc
</ul>
```

The `<li>`'s are created like this:

```
$("#NewItem").click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
        var itemCount = ($("[id^='item-']").length + 1);
        var element = $("<li id='item-" + itemCount + "'>" + itemCount + "</li>");
        $("#bxs").append(element);
    });
```

Now, everytime you create a box, it stores a key in localstorage with its id. So with 2 boxes the localstorage looks like this:

[image]

The value 'icon' is its background-image of each box.

My question is: on refresh or open, what is the best way to check if id exists (**such as 'bm-item-1', 'bm-item-2'**) and append the `<li>`'s/boxes.

Shall I create a new key of which will store how many boxes exist? And how can I parse them once you visit the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would use another way of storing you objects.

```
var result = [
    {id: 1, icon: "a"},
    {id: 2, icon: "a"}
];

for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
    var item = result[i];
    // item.id
    // item.icon
}
```

of course you need to change the way you store you're data at this point. Append a new object into the result array and re-save it. Anway I think you know how to manage that :)

**UPDATE**

I've created a basic example for you http://jsfiddle.net/manuel/29gtu/

Note that you need to include [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) for IE support of the JSON object

Comment: Can you explain me aittle bit on this please?

Comment: Thanks alot. Is the JSON 2 for all IE versions? The client doesn't want to support IE6 & 7.

Comment: the JSON object is support from version 8.0 so you don't need it unless you need to support ie 6 or 7

Comment: Can you please check my other similar question? You probably have an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087126/localstorage-if-the-id-of-a-li-exists-in-localstorage-alert

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this:

You can easily load the items to be displayed to users.

Just loop through all the items in local storage using Javascript as the page loads...

```
<body>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var item = "";//array to hold string values for each key value
var key ="";//array to hold string values for each key name
for (i=0;i < localStorage.length;i++) {

    var count = 0;
    if (key != "" | key != null) { //or matches what you're looking for
       item[count] = localStorage.getItem(key);
       key(i) = localStorage.key(i);
       count += 1;
    }

 }

function load_table()
{
if (item == "" || item == " " || item == null) {
   document.write("<div id=\"list_table\" style=\"display: block;\">");
   document.write("<h3>You have no stored items.</h3>");
   document.write("</div>");
}
else {
   document.write("<div id=\"list_table\" style=\"display: block;\">");
   document.write("<h3>Stored Items</h3>");
   document.write("<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">");

  for (i=0;i < item.length;i++) {
      document.write("<tr><td width=\"33%\" valign=\"top\">"+item(i)+"</td>");
      document.write("<td width=\"67%\" valign=\"top\" style=\"padding-left: 0px; text-transform: capitalize;\">"+key(i)+"</td></tr>");
   }
 }


document.write("</table>");
document.write("</div> <!-- end list_table div -->");
 } // end if (item != "")
} // end load_table
</script>
```

In the html, you stick a div that can be shown or hidden, in an appropriate place.

```
<div id="items_table" style="display: none;">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
//alert("calling load_table");
load_table();
//alert("DONE calling load_table");
</script>
</div>
```

You are probably wanting something in the lines of JQuery, but the idea is in there.