# Localstorage: If the ID of a <li> exists in localstorage alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, html-lists

I want to check if the ID of a `<li>` exists in localstorage to alert...

For example, the li's have id such as item-1, item-2, item-3 etc. In localstorage there is a value named **id** and it gets a string with the same name: item-1, item-2, item-3. I want to check, when I click on a li with id item-2, if that item-2 exists in localstorage to alert accordingly.

This is my HTML:

```
<ul id="bxs" class="tabs"> 
    <li id="item-1">1</li> 
    <li id="item-2">2</li> 
    <li id="item-3">3</li> 
    <li id="item-4">4</li> 
    <li id="item-5">5</li> 
</ul>
... etc
```

And this is what my localstorage looks like:

```
Key: result

Value: [{"id":"item-1","href":"google.com"},{"id":"item-2","href":"youtube.com"}]
```

etc.

I append the list like this:

```
var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("result"));
if(result != null) {
    for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
        var item = result[i];
        $("#bxs").append($("<li></li>").attr("id", item.id).html(item));

    }
}
```

and I want, when I click on the `<li>`'s to check if their ID exists as an '**id**' in localstorage and alert accordingly. Something like this:

```
$("#bxs").on('click', 'li',function() {
// if exists alert('exists') else alert('doesn't exists')   
    });
```

I tried this but it always alert that it doesn't exists:

```
var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("result"));
        if(result != null) {
            for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
                var item = result[i];
                if(item.id != null) {
                    alert('doesnt exists');
                }else {
                    alert('exists');

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you are

```
$("#bxs").on('click', 'li',function() {
    var exists = false
    for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
        var item = result[i];
        if(item.id == $(this).prop("id")) {
            exists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(exists) {
        alert("exists");
    }
    else {
        alert("doesn't exists");
    }
});
```